# How to get the network error response message from server side using Volley library?

Tags: android, web-services, android-volley, android-networking, android-webservice

I am trying to get the HTTP status code like 400, 401, or 500 from server side. I tried the code below but the message was `null`.

```
new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e("error fetched/////", "" + error.toString());
        // listener.onError(error.toString());
        String json = null;
        NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
        int errcode = error.networkResponse.statusCode;

        Log.e("errcode","errcode"+error.networkResponse.toString());

        Log.e("HttpStatus", String.valueOf(errcode));

        if(HttpStatus.SC_SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS==error.networkResponse.statusCode){
            Log.e("HttpStatus","HttpStatus");
        }
        if (response != null && response.data != null) {
            switch (response.statusCode) {
                case 400:
                    json = new String(response.data);
                    json = trimMessage(json, "message");
                    listener.onError(error.toString());
                    Log.e("listenerpost", "listenerpost" + error.getMessage());
                    break;

                case 401:
                    json = new String(response.data);
                    json = trimMessage(json, "message");
                    listener.onError(error.toString());
                    Log.e("listener1", "listener" + error.networkResponse.toString());
                    break;

                case 500:
                    json = new String(response.data);
                    json = trimMessage(json, "message");
                    listener.onError(error.toString());
                    Log.e("listener500", "listener500" + error.networkResponse.toString());
            }
            //Additional cases
        }
    }
})
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: what is the response you get from this: Log.e("errcode","errcode"+error.networkResponse.toString());

Comment: errcode   com.android.volley.NetworkResponse@1b5fef4b
this is the response from that. @djodjo

Comment: can do a log of json after " json = new String(response.data); " and can u paste your trimMessage also as it seems the issue is there

Comment: also by "got message as null." you mean 'json' variable or something else ?

Comment: Log.e("listenerpost", "listenerpost" + error.getMessage()); here i got null message.

Comment: I have checked "json = new String(response.data)"
here i have used wrong param for getting error message. Now working good using error_description param. Thanks @djodjo
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Provided Authorization Grant is invalid."}

Comment: yep i added an answer before if this want you want you can accept it  :)

Answer (score 0):

Override this method:

```
@Override
protected Response<byte[]> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
      // Here is what you need!
      response.statuscode;
}
```

Comment: Sry, you can remove that line. Copy paste.. :D

Answer (score 0):

The issues is that you are trying to get

> error.getMessage()

while this is null for the erros you are trying because [BasicNetwork](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/BasicNetwork.java) does:

```
else if (statusCode >= 400 && statusCode <= 499) {
                        // Don't retry other client errors.
                        throw new ClientError(networkResponse);
                    } else if (statusCode >= 500 && statusCode <= 599) {
                        if (request.shouldRetryServerErrors()) {
                            attemptRetryOnException("server",
                                    request, new ServerError(networkResponse));
                        }
```

Basically error is just an Exception class and message for ClientError and ServerError is not set.

the error information from the server is in

> error.networkResponse

and the way you get it should get the message from the server

> json = new String(response.data);